# Mongoose.js Error saving document with unusual but seemingly acceptable string value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm getting an error saving a document to mongoose.js from Node.js.  This code has worked fine for a while but it's now causing a problem with Javascript objects with key values that seem fine otherwise.

What's being saved is a document where one member is an associative array, which for simplicity have represented as `Schema.Types.Mixed`:

```
var formatSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  values: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: false}
});
```

It's now failing when one object has a key like `"0038-"`.  Specifically, it's the dash `-` that's causing the problem.  If I take those values out (for testing, not for user satisfaction) it loads fine.  Having isolated it this far am now stumped as to how to proceed.

```
[
  {
    "name": "INJURYF",
    "values": {
        "0": "No",
        "1": "Yes"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "RFVF",
    "values": {
        "10050": "Chills",
        "10100": "Fever",
        "10200": "General weakness",
        "10250": "General ill feeling",
        "00323": "Salmonella arthritis",
        "00324": "Salmonella osteomyelitis",
        "0038-": "Other specified salmonella infections",   // PROBLEM STARTS HERE
        "0039-": "Salmonella infection, unspecified",
        "0040-": "Shigella dysenteriae",
        ...
      }
    }, ...
  ]
```

Here's the specific error message,

```
Express
500 TypeError: Cannot call method 'path' of undefined
at getPositionalPath (/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:380:22)
at Schema.path (/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:199:9)
at Query._getSchema (/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1789:27)
at Query._walkUpdatePath (/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1721:16)
at Query._walkUpdatePath (/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1716:25)
at Query._castUpdate (/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1655:23)
at castDoc (/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2160:18)
at Query._findAndModify (/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2032:17)
at Query.findOneAndUpdate (/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1941:15)
at Function.Model.findOneAndUpdate (/myproject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:1127:16)
```

[Mongoose positional operator errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874617/mongoose-positional-operator-errors)

Comment: Please post some additional information: a) code which shows how you called findOneAndUpdate and b) which exact version of mongoose you are using. Thanks!

Comment: Actually post that as the answer.  I had installed mongoose.js just a few weeks ago so it didn't occur to me that might be the issue, but moving to version 3.3.1 fixed it magically.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go:

This is a bug of an older mongoose version - please update to the latest version.